# Adding Facebook Authentication to Rails Custom Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am currently creating a rails application that requires authentication. Currently, I'm doing custom authentication like that shown in in the following railscast episode:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised

I would, however, like to add the option to also Log-in through facebook. After doing some research, I found that the easiest way to add Facebook login involves using Devise/Omniauth for authentication. Would it be worth it to try and switch my authentication system to Devise/Omniauth, or is there an easier way to add facebook authentication? I have also looked at the Facebooker plugin, but it seems very outdated. Any suggestions? I am relatively new to Rails, so I appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Authlogic and Devise in conjunction with Omniauth (+ facebook/google/twitter/etc). I found that Devise is the better solution for me with all it's built in functionality. Getting it to work with Omniauth was a breeze. There's a great Railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised

I would definitely recommend going that route. Every piece of the pie is updated often and has great documentation so it should be easy to use for people still learning Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook authentication with Devise/Omniauth is mature, widely used, and well-documented. It would make sense to go with that.